# shift keyframe time in extendscript

Tags: extendscript, after-effects

I would like to shift the time of some keyframes on a layer to be x seconds/frames later. In the Extendsript documentation there is a [function](http://docs.aenhancers.com/properties/property/#property-setvalueatkey) for setting a keyframe's value, but none I could find for setting a keyframe's time.

I do not want to modify the layer's in/out points and this will need to be able to operate on selected keys only, so just shifting the layer around doesn't quite pan out as a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no actual **keyframe** object in the After Effects API. There are just properties, and a bunch of methods to get information about the keyframes of those properties.  For a program that is all about the keyframes this seems … kinda like the sorta thing Adobe *would* do.

So what you have to do is copy all the attributes of the key you want to move, like the temporal ease, spatial tangents and so on, then create a new key with those properties, then delete the original key (which can also be a gotcha, because if you've inserted the new key before the old key its index will have changed. This is infuriating). I wrote a function to do that which you can find [here](https://github.com/stibinator/stibsAEScripts/blob/master/(lib)/copyproperties-makekey.jsx), feel free to fork and improve.

I guess if I was better at JS I'd *make* a keyframe object.

Comment: Haha I just spent the majority of my day doing just the same. Thankfully David Torno's great extendscript tutorial series did cover this topic so I was able to get it working. I left my question up in case there was a better way... But as you said, this is very 'Adobe' to not improve this in 30 years or so...

Comment: But hay at least we got a content aware fill and roto brush that even work on one or two jobs a year!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this exact thing because I wanted to find out how to move all selected keyframes to the playhead using a keyboard hotkey.
I couldn't find out how to simulate mouse click and drag (if anybody knows, because that may be more trivial...), but I ended up making a script that first records all the keyframes, then deletes them all, then replaces them by a shifted value.

And yeah, it does involve making a "keyframe" object and storing them into an array.  The order of shiftKeyFrames will assume you recorded the keyframes into the array in left-right order.

```
var records = arrayOfkeyFrameObjects;

function shiftKeyFrames(records, dif){//shifts keyFrames by dif     

    for(i= records.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--){ //Remove original keyframes.
        records[i].property.removeKey(records[i].index);
    }

    for(i=0; i < records.length;i++){ 
        records[i].replacementIndex = records[i].property.addKey(roundFrame(records[i].time+dif)); //Adds a keyframe with the time difference, rounded to the nearest frame, and stores the replacement index.
        records[i].property.setValueAtKey(records[i].replacementIndex,records[i].value); //Sets the value of the new keyFrame
    }

    for(i=0; i < records.length;i++){
        records[i].property.setSelectedAtKey(records[i].replacementIndex, true); //Re-selects all the created keyframes.
    }
}

function roundFrame(time){
    return Math.round(comp.frameRate*time)/comp.frameRate;
}

function keyFrame(property, index){
    this.property = property;
    this.index = index;
    this.time = property.keyTime(index);
    this.value = property.keyValue(index);
    this.replacementIndex;
}
}());
```